# RewriteRule for subdomain to subfolder .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

1. non-http force to https - **works**
2. www force to non-www - **works**
3. website loaded from subfolder (/web) - **works**
4. **test.example.com load different subfolder (/test) - does not work**

4, Does not work, the condition is met to go to /web. Can't understand how to change this into /test

**the .htaccess code I use:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example/web/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your htaccess file in your question. Could you please confirm if for only url `test.example.com` you want to change it to `test.example.com/test` in browser? Also on which url you want to apply web?(is it s redirect in browser?) Please confirm on these 2 queries, thank you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.

I want test.example.com to load the content of the folder /test but without showing it in the URL. just like example.com is doing.

so also for test.example.com/whatever loads fromt the folder /test/whatever

Comment: Sure, how about non existing pages? Do you want it to serve with index.php or index.html file?

Comment: non existing should give error 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following htaccess rules file here. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. In case you have further more rules(apart from shown ones) then make sure these Rules are before those rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
##Apply https to uris here..
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

##Apply non-www to uris here..
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

##Apply test to all uris here..
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ example/web/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

##Apply test to all uris here..
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ www.example.com/test/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for your script. But I think with this code the last rule in the given script is being forgotten?

the non test.example URLS should load from the /example/web folder

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example/web/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

Comment: @Ole, I have changed the last rule's condition now, could you please check it once and let me know how it goes, thank you.

Comment: what i'm trying to explain is that the request: example.com should load from the folder /example/web(this is not being served in your code). And the request test.example.com should load from the folder /test.

Comment: @Ole, ok sure, I have updated rules file accordingly now, please check my updated rules file and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Ole, Could you ;please rollback your question changes, please keep it with your original used htaccess else it confuses users/all, thank you.

Comment: I'll change it back after solution is working. I want to show you the real life situation.

Comment: @Ole, Sorry, I can't join chat room, we could comment here, thank you.

Comment: Okay. Did you have a look at the real life situation? Do you understand why it is proving a 404 now when test.example.com is loaded?

Comment: @Ole, I am sorry I didn't get it, could you please explain it more with samples here in comments.

Comment: what is happening now is that when test.example.com is requested, test.example.com/test is loaded (i think).

But the folder that should be loaded is located at: www.example.com/test.

so now it is providing 404.

Comment: @Ole, so is `www.example.com/test` a folder present at your system?

Comment: yes www.example.com/test ps present. That is the folder where the test.example.com should load from.

Comment: @Ole, ok sure, I have edited my rules now, please check it once and let me know how it goes.